# Как преобразовать такой формат вывода времени в f-строку?

Tags: python, строки, время, форматирование

На одном сайте встретил такой пример с форматом вывода времени выполнения кода:

```
import time
start = time.monotonic()
time.sleep(15)
result = time.monotonic() - start
print("Program time: {:>.3f}".format(result) + " seconds.")

Program time: 15.012 seconds.
```

Не могу разобрать (что округление до трех цифр понятно из результата работы принта) пример форматирования

> {:>.3f}".format(result)

И как это переложить на f-строку.
Спасибо.

Comment: `print(f"Program time: {result:>.3f} seconds.")`

Comment: Спасибо!
Только что тоже нашел опытным путем и гуглом похожий ответ.
У меня получилось так: print(f"Время выполнения: {format(result, ':>.3f')} секунд")